# Acessar região de memória que ja foi desalocada

Tags: c#, servidor

Estou no processo final de desenvolvimento de um programa e me deparei com um erro, já passei um tempo pesquisando e não consegui resolver o problema.

### Sobre o programa:

Em resumo, o programa recebe e escreve valores num outro programa (Aspen HYSYS) e se comunica com servidores OPC escrevendo e recebendo valores.

### Alguns detalhes para esclarecer mais:

Para atualizar os valores no formulário principal, eu criei 3 threads, uma recebe os valores do servidor e escreve no programa, uma pega os valores do programa e escreve no servidor e a outra tem o princípio da primeira, como uma thread secundária não pode alterar nada na interface dos formulários, cada thread faz um invoke que chama um delegate para atualizar os valores no programa.

*Para se comunicar com os servidores OPC, eu uso duas DLL's da Softing.*

## Meu problema:

Quando eu dou o comando de atualizar os valores, aparece o seguinte erro: "Attempt to read or write protected memory. This is often an idication that other memory is corrupt.". Pelo que eu pesquisei, é como se eu tivesse tentando escrever num espaço de memória que ja foi desalocado. Explicitamente, eu não desaloquei nada, mas algum método da Softing pode ter desalocado ou excluído a referência sem eu saber.

O erro não acontece em uma linha específica, ele varia entre métodos de leitura e escrita no servidor.

### Trecho de código em que o erro acontece:

```
if (opcform.plcopc.URL == null)
{
   opcform.plcopc.URL =     opcform.plcopc.getURL(opcform.GridExport.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString(),opcform.GridExport.Rows[i]Cells[7].Value.ToString());
//o método acima apenas pega a URL do servidor
   opcform.plcopc.m_daSession = new DaSession(opcform.plcopc.URL);<<<<<<<<<<<<
//instancia uma sessão no servidor com a URL do mesmo
   opcform.plcopc.m_daSubscription = new DaSubscription(500, opcform.plcopc.m_daSession); <<<<<<<<<
//instancia um objeto necessário para fazer as leituras e escritas de forma síncrona e adiciona ele a sessão
}

opcform.plcopc.m_daItem = new DaItem(opcform.GridExport.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString(), opcform.plcopc.m_daSubscription); <<<<<<<<<<<

opcform.plcopc.exOptions.ExecutionType = EnumExecutionType.SYNCHRONOUS;
//seta que a comunicação vai ser síncrona
if (opcform.plcopc.m_daSession.CurrentState != EnumObjectState.CONNECTED)
{
    opcform.plcopc.m_daSession.Connect(true, true, opcform.plcopc.exOptions);
//conecta com o servidor
}
int retorno;
double vl = Convert.ToDouble(opcform.GridExport.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
//pega o valor que vai ser escrito no servidor
ValueQT vt = new ValueQT(vl, EnumQuality.GOOD, DateTime.Now);
//o objeto que vai ser escrito no servidor
opcform.plcopc.m_daItem.Write(vt, out retorno, opcform.plcopc.exOptions);<<<<<<
//escrevendo o objeto no servidor
```

### Tentativas:

Bem, como são em muitas linhas o problema, eu não consegui pensar em muita coisa, já tentei dar um "lock" em alguns objetos, mas outros erros apareceram.

### Meu pedido

Bem, alguém pode me dizer se tem como eu "bloquear" a referência para que só eu possa apaga-la? ou como eu posso monitorar para saber aonde ela é apagada?

Por favor, respondam de forma teórica, não precisa digitar milhares de linhas de código e acabar desperdiçando o tempo de vocês. Materiais para que eu possa buscar solução serão muito bem vindos.

Comment: Dê mais detalhes sobre e como o erro ocorre. Isto parece ser algum problema das DLLs que você está usando. O .Net não deixa você acessar a memória do jeito que bem entende. O código que você apresentou não apresenta nenhum problema aparente. É possível que algum método chamado nele esteja fazendo o que não deve. Você usa bloco `unsafe` em algum lugar do seu código? Esta seria a única forma de fazer algo mais abusivo na memória. Fora isto, é o uso de recursos nativos que fogem do controle do .Net que está causando o problema. A não ser que eu lembre de mais alguma coisa.

Comment: só coloquei um trecho do método, pois ele é grande, o que o método faz é pegar as informações que estão num DataGrid view, que o usuário insere, buscar o servidor(terceira linha do código que eu mostrei), a partir daí são coisas "padrão" da DLL para se comunicar com um servidor OPC (acho que descrevi isso bem no código),  o problema é que eu não tenho acesso a DLL, o único método criado por mim no código acima foi o getURL(). Se o bloco unsafe é utilizado, é na DLL, não usei no meu código. Mas você sabe se tem alguma forma de saber (algum tipo de debug) aonde a bagunça esta sendo feita?

Comment: Eu me perguntei se isso pode ter sido causado pelo Garbage Colector, se ele pode ter apagado alguma referência, será que tem como eu bloquear o GC de excluir determinadas coisas até que meu programa seja finalizado?

Comment: Concordo com o @bigown, parece-me que estás a chamar código *unmanaged*, e vais ter de usar `GCHandle.Alloc` + `GCHandleType.Pinned` para impedir o GC de mover os teus objectos enquanto estão a ser usados pelo código unmanaged

Comment: vou pesquisar sobre isso e tentar resolver o problema com isso, obrigado

Comment: Você tem algum material que pode me ajudar a utilizar estes métodos?

Comment: @YanJovita eu não fui muito a fundo não, mas nas pesquisas que eu fiz no google, me parece que o problema não tem muito a ver com o software (dll) em si, mas com alguns patches aplicados em servidores (especialmente .NET 3.5 ou superior) em ambientes `Medium-Trust` e com determinados drivers (NVidea, Antivirus, etc). Muitos simplesmentes descobriram o driver/software que estava gerando o erro e tiraram.. ou moveram para um ambiente Full Trust.

Comment: Não sei se compreendi muito bem, você esta sugerindo que pode ser um problema externo?

Comment: @YanJovita sim estou sim. Vou postar aqui.

Comment: Este erro está parecendo que o módulo externo tem um BUG!

Answer (score 1):

Yan, como havia sugerido nos comentários acima, algumas pessoas no SO encontraram um problema parecido e sugeriram que era um problema externo. Não sei se isto irá ajudar você mas segue algumas coisas que encontrei nestes links:

- Esta resposta no SO aqui sugeriu que o erro estava em uma placa de vídeo da NVidea, que acabava gerando o problema (wow!!!!!!!!!):

  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074585/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-this-is-often-an-indication-that-ot
- Este outro, embora seja um software comercial, identificou que alguns servidores em que a aplicação dele estão instalados estão em `MediumTrust`, e para solucionar o problema colocaram em `FullTrust`:

http://manual.aspdotnetstorefront.com/p-1239-attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory.aspx

Realmente eu não sei se ajuda, mas vale a pena dar uma investigada. Especialmente o primeiro link, o desenvolvedor dá o passo a passo em como ele chegou na raiz do problema usando o WinDBG (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Estava olhando o primeiro, ele localizou o erro usando dois softwares, o WinDBG e o SOS, eu tentei fazer o debug no meu programa usando o WinDBG, não pareceu ajudar, não sei se usei corretamente, vou testar o SOS. Mas muito obrigado pela sua ajuda desde já!